# Xamarin на слабом ПК

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Как изучать мобильную разработку на Xamarin, если мой ноут не способен запустить эмулятор для дебага приложения? Имеется 8гб ОЗУ, но андроид студио и xamarin для меня превращаются один сплошной фриз при запуске. Пробовал разные эмуляторы, в лучшем случае вижу черный экран спустя несколько минут. Раньше же как-то разрабатывали приложения. Если есть обходные пути, буду рад услышать.

Comment: Относительно: "Раньше же как-то разрабатывали приложения." - полагаю, делали это на устаревших сейчас версиях, которые писались под железо, современное на тот момент. С ростом уровня железа растут и требования софта. Т.е. вам или старую версию софта какую-то ставить (с возможными ограничениями в обучении) либо как-то увеличивать мощность, например, как @Olegator36 предложил. Вообще, у эмулятора должны же быть требования к машине - посмотрите, что им не соответствует? Можно ещё доставить что-то на машину, но вариант сомнительный. И сложно может быть, и дорого.

Answer (score 1):

В андроид студио можно подключить физическое устройство (ваш телефон). Оперативная память тратится, но будет работать лучше. Просто подключите телефон по USB и включите режим отладки. 8 гб вполне должно хватать. Наверное лагает именно эмулятор, так что попробуйте.